# What "Wolverine and the X-Men" collections concern Toad & Husk's relationship?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, wolverine-and-the-x-men

Trying to find *Wolverine and the X-Men* paperbacks that deal with the relationship Toad built with Husk, up to the point where he joined the Hellfire Academy with her and Quentin Quire, and where the two broke up shortly afterwards.

Comment: Voted to leave open as  _Wolverine and the X-Men_ ran for 43 issues, and Toad and Husk were relatively minor characters, so this is a definite and pretty narrow list (we have other questions like this) cf [this meta (for instance)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17/98028)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complete list of *Wolverine and the X-Men* issues featuring both Toad and Husk can be obtained with [this Google query](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22toad%20mortimer%22%20%22husk%20paige%22%20%22wolverine%20and%20the%20x-men%20vol%201%22%20site:marvel.wikia.com) (16 results), however that doesn't mean they will interact.

The issues where they do interact, however, are listed below. *For the sake of readability, all panels are linked to but not included, as it would distort the bullet list.*

- [Issue #9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILQDI.png): Toad meets Husk after saving someone from a fall (by catching him with his tongue). Husk is impressed;
- [Issue #14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwQPm.jpg): Toad and Husk attend the same meeting, and Toad hopes to keep one of her sheds, and fantasizes about having tea with it. Up to the reader to judge how creepy that is;
- [Issue #15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKCYV.png): Toad and Husk spend some quality time in the nice caves miles below the school;
- [Issue #18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NFiE.jpg) and [#19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duuML.png): Husk resigns and mentions Toad on her way out; she tells him to stay at the school and not to follow her for the time being;
- [Issue #30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCpha.png), [#31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvfCh.png), [#32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CgAF.png): Toad joins the Hellfire Academy, along with Omega Kid (Quentin Quire); there, he's still trapped in a janitor role; Husk breaks up (of sorts) with him after he "embarassed" her upon suggesting some Hellfire kids don't want to be bad guys;
- [Issue #35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcr8w.jpg): Toad shreds Husk's layers (as she was going berserk), which causes her to loose her Hellfire Academy memories, along with Toad's love (although it's revealed she's willing to give it a new shot in issue #41).

They're all collected in paperbacks, either the big fat one collecting all 43 issues of the *Wolverine and the X-Men* run ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785190244)) or shorter volumes collecting 5 volumes each, such as [this one for the "Hellfire" arc](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785166009) (that is, issues #30 to #35 - which is probably the one in which you'll see the most of Toad/Husk interaction).

Comment: They're sweet, in a way.

Comment: IKR? One of few times Toad is actually happy

Comment: Nice. Exactly what I was looking for. Just curious, what were your opinions on the 2 as a couple?

Comment: @Gothamite24 glad to have helped! No particular opinion, to be honest I wasn't a big fan of WATXM in general :/ (partially related, but should we discuss that further, it'd probably be best to take it to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe))