# In what Marvel paperbacks do Toad's Brotherhood of Mutants appear?

Tags: marvel, comics, suggested-order

As far as I know, Toad's Brotherhood of Mutants was first introduced in *X-Force* and included the characters of Blob, Phantazia, Pyro, and Sauron. I was therefore wondering which paperbacks I should read to explore this version of the Brotherhood, as Toad is personally one of my favorite Marvel villains.

Comment: Seems like this is more of a recommendation question at present, that can't be answered with anything other than opinion, which isn't allowed, or a mere list of every TPB they appear in which is, I guess, but is a bit of a chore for potential answerers so you should be clear if that's what you want.

Comment: What I want is to see what paperbacks Toad's Brotherhood originates in and ends, nothing more. Also, don't quite see how this is too broad as the Marvel Wiki states that this Brotherhood was short-lived.

Comment: Just to be clear, I am simply looking for a list of paperbacks they appear in. As I stated earlier, this Brotherhood was apparently short-lived, so shouldn't be too much of a hassle

Comment: Voted to reopen as, upon reading what OP is looking for precisely and some research, this is a pretty short list (similar to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/201613/98028), which was left open): less than 10 appearances between 1991 and 1993. Short enough to be on topic, I reckon.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Toad's saliva as such. Therefore I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toad's Brotherhood of Evil Mutants was indeed short-lived (less than 10 appearances between 1991 and 1993). The issues featuring it are listed below. *For the sake of readability, all panels are linked to but not included, as it would distort the formatting.*

## *X-Force*

This Brotherhood was created in [*X-Force* #5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKBLO.png) (1991). Toad, already in league with the Blob, manages to bring Sauron out of Karl Lykos, in order to "fullfill his dreams" of a new Brotherhood of Evil Mutants. By [issue #6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B0gO.png) (1992), Phantazia and Pyro have already joined (we don't get to know how).

They're battling X-Force in [issue #7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIZ1j.jpg), Sauron is on his own in issue #8, he's rejoined by Blob and Phantazia in issue #9. They're defeated and none to be seen again in *X-Force*. Well, technically they do appear on a monitor in [*X-Force Annual* #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mChel.png), but that's not really relevant.

Collected in the paperback print of the "Under the gun" arc ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1302904574)).

## *X-Factor*

They serve as "villain of the week" in [*X-Factor* #82](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyouY.png) (1992). They try to enroll people, are stopped by X-Factor fairly easily, and that's a day.

It's really a one-issue thing, and [is printed as such](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000RH3BUW), although I'd imagine the issue is also collected with other *X-Factor* issues not featuring Toad's Brotherhood.

## *Darkhawk* and *Sleepwalker*

In [*Darkhawk* #19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PupCp.jpg) (1992), the Brotherhood plots yet another scheme, "saving" Portal to get him to join them. That fails (surprisingly), Portal helps in pushing them back. They get their payback in the next issue, when they mind-control [Portal as a taxi driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH8ta.jpg). He's saved from the Brotherhood by Darkhawk and Spider-Man in [*Sleepwalker* #17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYyvL.png) (1992), right after teleporting the evil team to an unknown place.

As far as I can tell these three aren't collected in *one* paperback, but they're available in single-issues on Amazon, ComicBookRealm and the like.

## *X-Men Unlimited*

The team is sunbathing on a boat in [*X-Men Unlimited* #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmJyE.png) (1993), when Exodus comes and states that Phantazia is eligible for a place in a brand-new sanctuary. Phantazia goes team player and declines.

[Collected in single-issue](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000LK0KS6), although I guess it's the same situation as *X-Factor* one above.

## *X-Men*

In [*X-Men Annual* #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6g2r.jpg) (1993), the Brotherhood faces (among others) Jonathan Chambers, an energy vampire (ask the Blob). Toad has a minor role in the issue.

Printed in one-issue thingy, sold by various individuals throughout the Internet. *X-Factor* situation from above applies once again.

As far as I can tell, that's it. Toad's Brotherhood doesn't appear after that, so it's rather safe to say Toad's Brotherhood disbanded after the events listed above. Given their success rate, that had to happen at some point.

Comment: Thank you for saving us from multiple Rob Liefeld panels.